# Long to wide data frame with selected columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I need help with this conversion I have been stuck in.

I have a long data frame which contains simulation data (i.e 10k simulations) along with other features.

I want to convert this long data frame to wide data frame **BUT** want each simulation in a separate row.

I tried default long to wide conversion methods but they make each simulation a new feature (But I want each simulation in a new row)

Dummy dataset:

```
name1 <- c('frame1','frame1','frame1','frame1','frame1','frame1','frame1','frame1','frmae1','frame1',
           'frame2','frame2','frame2','frame2','frame2','frame2','frame2','frame2','frmae2','frame2')

name2 <- c('arch','conf','f.time.c','f.rev.c','sim1.f','sim1.val','sim2.f','¨sim2.val','sim3.f','sim3-val',
           'arch','conf','f.time.c','f.rev.c','sim1.f','sim1.val','sim2.f','¨sim2.val','sim3.f','sim3.val')
value <- c('x86','cust','100','20','-a -b -c=10','150','-d -e=1 -f -z -x','40','-r -e -f -r','89',
           'x24','default','500','2','-a1 -b34 -c=12','99','-a -e','100','-e -z ','120')

df = data.frame(name1,name2,value)
```

data set looke like this:

```
   name1     name2            value
1  frame1      arch              x86
2  frame1      conf             cust
3  frame1  f.time.c              100
4  frame1   f.rev.c               20
5  frame1    sim1.f      -a -b -c=10
6  frame1  sim1.val              150
7  frame1    sim2.f -d -e=1 -f -z -x
8  frame1  sim2.val               40
9  frmae1    sim3.f      -r -e -f -r
10 frame1  sim3.val               89
-------------- Simulation for frame 1 end here
11 frame2      arch              x24
12 frame2      conf          default
13 frame2  f.time.c              500
14 frame2   f.rev.c                2
15 frame2    sim1.f   -a1 -b34 -c=12
16 frame2  sim1.val               99
17 frame2    sim2.f            -a -e
18 frame2  sim2.val              100
19 frmae2    sim3.f             -e -z 
20 frame2  sim3.val              120
```

I want to convert it to data frame like this: (with repetition of feature for different sim )

```
   frame arch    conf f.time.c f.rev.c sim_number            sim.f vale
1 frame1  x86    cust      100      20       sim1      -a -b -c=10  150
2 frame1  x86    cust      100      20       sim2 -d -e=1 -f -z -x   40
3 frame1  x86    cust      100      20       sim3      -r -e -f -r   89
4 frame2  x24 default      500       2       sim1   -a1 -b34 -c=12   99
5 frame2  x24 default      500       2       sim2            -a -e  100
6 frame2  x24 default      500       2       sim3            -e -z  120
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a combination of data.table's `dcast` and `melt` functions.

1. Cast to wide format based on the entire `name2` column with values based on the `value` column.
2. Melt back to a longer format using the columns starting with `sim` (e.g. `sim1.f` and `sim1.val`)

```r
library(data.table)

## cast to wide format
df_wide <- dcast(setDT(df), name1 ~ name2, value.var = "value")

## melt back a selection of columns
melt(df_wide, 
    measure.vars = patterns("\\.f$", "\\.val$"), 
    variable.name = "sim_number",
    value.name = c("sim.f", "value")
)
#>     name1 arch    conf f.rev.c f.time.c sim_number            sim.f value
#> 1: frame1  x86    cust      20      100          1      -a -b -c=10   150
#> 2: frame2  x24 default       2      500          1   -a1 -b34 -c=12    99
#> 3: frame1  x86    cust      20      100          2 -d -e=1 -f -z -x    40
#> 4: frame2  x24 default       2      500          2            -a -e   100
#> 5: frame1  x86    cust      20      100          3      -r -e -f -r    89
#> 6: frame2  x24 default       2      500          3           -e -z    120
```

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(name1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("frame1", 
"frame2"), class = "factor"), name2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L), .Label = c("arch", "conf", "f.rev.c", "f.time.c", "sim1.f", 
"sim1.val", "sim2.f", "sim2.val", "sim3.f", "sim3.val"), class = "factor"), 
    value = structure(c(19L, 16L, 7L, 11L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 12L, 6L, 
    14L, 18L, 17L, 13L, 10L, 3L, 15L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L), .Label = c("-a -b -c=10", 
    "-a -e", "-a1 -b34 -c=12", "-d -e=1 -f -z -x", "-e -z ", 
    "-r -e -f -r", "100", "120", "150", "2", "20", "40", "500", 
    "89", "99", "cust", "default", "x24", "x86"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

NB: I replaced '¨sim2.val' by 'sim2.val' and 'frmae2' and 'frmae1' by 'frame2' and 'frame1' respectively in the original data.

Answer (score 2):

A possible (but not really lean) `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(
    name1 = gsub("frmae", "frame", name1),
    sim_number = gsub("^.*(sim\\d+).*", "\\1", name2),
    name2 = gsub("^sim.*f$", "sim.f", name2),
    name2 = gsub("^.*sim\\d+.*val$", "sim.val", name2)
  ) %>%
  spread(name2, value) %>%
  group_by(name1) %>%
  fill(names(.)) %>% fill(names(.), .direction = 'up') %>%
  filter(grepl("sim", sim_number))
```

Giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   name1 [2]
  name1  sim_number arch  conf    f.rev.c f.time.c sim.f            sim.val
  <chr>  <chr>      <fct> <fct>   <fct>   <fct>    <fct>            <fct>  
1 frame1 sim1       x86   cust    20      100      -a -b -c=10      150    
2 frame1 sim2       x86   cust    20      100      -d -e=1 -f -z -x 40     
3 frame1 sim3       x86   cust    20      100      -r -e -f -r      89     
4 frame2 sim1       x24   default 2       500      -a1 -b34 -c=12   99     
5 frame2 sim2       x24   default 2       500      -a -e            100    
6 frame2 sim3       x24   default 2       500      "-e -z "         120
```

Comment: This solution works, but in the process it creates rows for every other fetaure. In my case I have 200 features other than simulation features and it creates new rows (duplicated) for each one of them. Although it filters only sim data at the end but could be slow.

Comment: Indeed, this is why I said it is not really a lean approach. Apart from what you mention it also uses `fill` which is known to be slow. A strategy could be to replace it with `na.locf` etc.